# Confused by a phrase I heard in Downton Abbey

Tags: grammar, british-english

I'm a native English speaker and I know that the English spoken in the show by the aristocracy is in the dialect of received pronunciation.

I've been learning about the various dialects in England from back then up to the modern day but I heard a phrase on the show that sounded very odd to me and was wondering if someone with more knowledge **could explain it grammatically**.

The phrase is: "Don't let's make too much of it."  The context is the speaker telling someone not to make a big deal of out of something.

Comment: You wrote "lets", that would be "let's", as a contraction of "let us".

Comment: Fixed.  Sorry typo, it's early here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Don't let's fight"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59789/dont-lets-fight)

Comment: You didn't specify which variety of English you speak or were brought up in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may be confusing you is that the phrase *don't let's* generally means something different from *do not let us*. I also believe *don't let's* is primarily a British phrase.

*Don't let's* means *let us not*, while *do not let us* means *do not allow us to.* And the intermediate contraction *don't let us* can mean either one.

This was dealt with in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59789/dont-lets-fight), so I'm voting to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: You’re exactly right. That’s the part that was confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

"Don't let's make too much of it."

From the idiom:

**make (too) much of someone or something**

> to pay too much attention to someone or something

[TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+much+of)

Thus the sentence is question:

> Don't let us pay too much attention to ...

Comment: Typically used in the sense of showing concern over something worrisome. A daughter's choice of boyfriend, for instance. It's a request to downplay something, often by feigning acceptance or condescension (in the older sense of the word). If the subject was baiting you, let's not rise to the bait.

Comment: But *don't let's* and *do not let us* mean two different things. *Don't let's* means *let us not*. *Do not let us* means *Do not allow us to*. And *don't let us* can be used for either one. I think that's what  is confusing the OP.

Comment: let's = let us.

Comment: So "Let's go to the park, Mom" means the same thing as "Let us go to the park, Mom"?